# Using smartsheet-python-sdk to put data back into Smartsheet

Tags: python, api, sdk, smartsheet-api

I used the smartsheet-python-sdk (with a unique API key from Smartsheet) to automatically pull data from Smartsheet into my Python script along with other data sources (from Tableau) to create new feature-engineered columns. I now want to put these new columns I've created back into the same Smartsheet file I initially pulled from. Is there an automatic way to put these new columns I created back into the same Smartsheet I initially pulled data from using the smartsheet-python-sdk? Thank you!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the REST API documentation shows how to do it via the Python API in the examples on the right sidebar. (https://smartsheet.redoc.ly/)

I find the Python API woefully under-documented, but a) it closely parallels the REST API with a few differences, like parameters being in Pythonic snake_case instead of JS camelCase; and b) the examples are usually enough to get you there.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).